# How to transfer files between Windows and Linux via a cloud drive without messing up the names?

Tags: linux, windows-10, encoding, filenames, utf-8

Because Windows and Linux use different encodings (I think CP-1252 and UTF-8 respectively), when I upload a file in a non-ASCII language to a cloud drive from one OS then download it in the other, the name of the file gets messed up.

Is there a more convenient way than [iconv](https://linux.die.net/man/1/iconv) to transfer the files through the cloud drive without the names getting messed up?

*I'm using 7z to compress / decompress the files.

Comment: You should configure whatever you're using to edit the thing on Windows to use UTF-8.  All major editors should support that.

Answer (score 0):

If you use git, you could set up a private repo online, somewhere like GitHub or GitLab, then push and pull the files that way. On the Windows machine, I'd say to push to git unix-style and pull windows style. On the Linux machine, I'd say push and pull unix-style.